# Computing Euclidean distances between 2 matrices in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm writing a program with CUDA and the problem is the following:

- Two matrices A (n * 128) and B (m * 128)
- I take the first row of A, and I compute the distance between that vector and all the rows of B, one by one.
- I write the result of each distance on a row of a matrix C, so the element C(i,j) of C contains the distance between row i of A and row j of B.

-and I proceed with the next row of A.

I've implemented it this way:
I've got a grid made by ( n * m ) blocks, and 128 threads per block. ( 1 * 128 ).

The program is compiling, but the problem is that it doesn't gives good distances.
I can't figure out what wrong...

PS: I have CUDA 6.0 with a NVIDIA GTX 650 (copute capability 3.0)

```
 __global__ void EuclidianDistances( float *A, float *B , float *C , int n , int m)
{
    // SIZE is equal to 128
__shared__ float accumResult[SIZE];
__shared__ float sA[SIZE];
__shared__ float sB[SIZE];

    // MAPPING
int bx = blockIdx.x;  // n
int by = blockIdx.y;  // m
int ty = threadIdx.y; // 128
int tx = threadIdx.x; // 1


sA[ty] = A [bx * SIZE + ty];
sB[ty] = B [by * SIZE + ty];
__syncthreads();


accumResult[ty] = (sA[ty] - sB[ty])*(sA[ty] - sB[ty]);
__syncthreads();


// Parallel tree-reduction
for (int stride = SIZE/2 ; stride < 0 ; stride >>= 1)
    if (ty < stride)
    {
        accumResult[ty] += accumResult [stride + ty];
          __syncthreads();
    }

    // Writing results to output matrix
if ((threadIdx.y == 0))
    C [bx * m + by] = accumResult[ty];
       __syncthreads();
}
```

Comment: `(ty < pas)`, what is this `pas` ? And putting `__syncthreads();` inside an `if` statement depending of `threadIdx` looks dangerous to me.

Comment: Also: the condition seems wrong: `for (int stride = SIZE/2 ; stride < 0 ; stride >>= 1)`

Comment: @Levans : Sorry, `pas` is `stride`. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition looks wrong:

```
for (int stride = SIZE/2 ; stride < 0 ; stride >>= 1)
```

assuming SIZE is 128 as you said, this will not be executed. Also the `__synchthread` inside the if statement might stall the entire thing

---

Edit: after reading OP's comments I realized this is a language problem.. here is a snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int SIZE = 128;

    for (int stride = SIZE/2 ; stride < 0 ; stride >>= 1)
        cout << "Hello I'm running" << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/AyhXYF

The output is: nothing. Take a look at the [for loop syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) in C++, the second part is the condition that **should last for the entire duration of the loop**. If you start with a false condition, your loop is never going to be executed.

Comment: I just changed `pas` to `stride`. sorry, my mistake. So why is the condition wrong?

Comment: @Jeb11 his answer is still valid, didn't you mean `stride > 0` instead of `stride < 0` ?

Comment: @Levans it's working now with `stride > 0`, thank you. I think i'm going to remove this post , the solution is pretty obvious..

Comment: @Jeb11 sounds a bit depressing since I wanted to get some rep points, but all right.. fair enough if you learned from your mistake :)

Comment: @Marco A. I just accepted your answer. I ll keep my question online ;)

Comment: @MarcoA. My Kernel is giving me now good results and perform fastly when the size n and m of the 2 matrices are between 0 and 2000. But when I take n and m greater than 10000, it takes 20 seconds... Do you know how I could increase the kernel efficiency in usch cases?

Comment: That would probably be a different question but you might take a look at where your bottleneck is (i.e. memory or computation). Nsight can be helpful in this